# How can I create a generic function to sort an array of structures?

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, struct, bubble-sort

I'm working on this program for my University exam. I need to sort passenger array with a sorting algorithm (I choose bubblesort due to it's simplicity).
I need to create a generic function and pass as formal parameters:
-a list of objects i want to sort;
-a sort criterion.

So I think that I'll have to create only 1 Increasing sorting function and 1 decreasing sorting function and pass them the parameters to sort by.

I already tried to pass char *file_name to function, but I think that I'm wrong.

```
int passengersIncreasingBubbleSort_Birthyear(passengers test[], int x) {
    int i = 0, j = 0, min_idx, flag = 0;

    passengers temp;

    for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        min_idx = i;
        for (j = i + 1; j < x; j++) {
            if (test[j].birth_date.year < test[min_idx].birth_date.year) {
                min_idx = j;
            }
        }
        temp = test[min_idx];
        test[min_idx] = test[i];
        test[i] = temp;
        flag = 1;
    }

    return flag;
}
```

I tried this:

```
int passengersIncreasingBubbleSort_Birthyear(passengers test[], int x, char *value1, char *value2) {
    int i = 0, j = 0, min_idx, flag = 0;

    passengers temp;

    for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        min_idx = i;
        for (j = i + 1; j < x; j++) {
            if (value1 < value2) {
                min_idx = j;
            }
        }
        temp = test[min_idx];
        test[min_idx] = test[i];
        test[i] = temp;
        flag = 1;
    }

    return flag;
}
```

But it doesn't work as expected.

Ok, I achieved it.

```
int cmpfunction_Increasing_Birthdate (const void * a, const void * b)
{

  passengers *passengerA = (passengers *)a;
  passengers *passengerB = (passengers *)b;

  return ( passengerA->signup_date.year - passengerB->signup_date.year );
}
```

and this is my call:

```
    qsort(array, x, sizeof(passengers), cmpfunction_Increasing_Birthdate);
```

Now the question is, how can I also compare both year, month and day? Could I do it in the same compare function?

Comment: what's the purpose of `value1` and `value2` ? Their values don't change within the loop.

Comment: 1. I don't understand what `char *value1` and `char *value2` are supposed to represent.  2. This looks like maybe selection sort, not bubble sort.  3. what do you mean by a "sort criterion"?  do you perhaps mean a function pointer as a comparator?  4.  What if the birth years are equal?  Are you supposed to break ties by month and/or day?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to use a faster, albeit slightly more complex, sorting algorithm?  Bubble sort is O(n^2) and generally only used for teaching purposes.  Better:  Heap sort, merge sort, quick sort, etc.

Comment: `qsort` is an example of a generic sorting API that is already available to use in C. You turn your criteria into a comparison function that will be called by `qsort` internally to determine the order of elements. There is no reason you cannot do the same.

Comment: That model is the model you will need to follow for any type of "generic" sorting routine. You will pass a pointer to the array to be sorted, the number of elements, the size of each element (for swap purposes), and a pointer to a compare function. Within your sort function you will pass pointers to the elements to be compared to -- the compare function, and then based on the return from your compare `-1, 0, 1` you will know which of the two elements passed sort before, are equal to, or sort after the other and you swap accordingly.

Comment: If you want an example of a function that is able to sort an array of structures (or anything else) then look up the function `qsort()` - which is specified in the C standard, and declared in the standard header `<stdlib.h>` - for an example.     No need to look up an actual implementation of that function.  It is the interface to the function (the type of arguments it accepts, their meaning, and description of what it does) that is important.